# python --version is stuck for more than 10 minutes without printing anything

Tags: python

I'm having a severe problem with my pc and I can't even say what the problem is.

Basically what I did before that happened was:

- publish a repository to github.
- then copy all my python imports to a new file called imports.py
- try to run the main.py with the import file.

After getting this "error" I:

- removed the files again and put everything like it was.
- restarted my computer and retried to locate any suspicious files in the task manager

Since then, I can't use any of the commands in Visual Studio code. I'm not getting an error, I'm basically getting a permanent empty load command like this:

[image: cmd prompt]

[image: I know I wrote the version wrong. but even here nothing happens]

This is after 10 minutes of leaving it alone. (Yeah I spelled it wrong, but still no reaction)

I've reinstalled Python. Any idea what I can do next? Other commands like `ping google.com` seem to work.

Edit1: `py --version` is working but not python or python3.

Can I change my system (win 10) to start the py command?

Edit2: @esqew I opened the link and followed it. this is my Aliases:
[image]

And I'm getting 3 pip icons too

Edit 3": `where python` now doesn't give me a response. however I have these files in the same folder and when right-clicking it, are crashing my explorer. in addition, deleting these files doesn't work because of an unexpected error:
[image]
Sincerely Pascal

Comment: Where have you downloaded Python from? Please post the full download link.

Comment: You are experiencing something unusal. `python --version` should work, print a message and exit in less than a second on most systems.

Comment: what is the result of `which python` (or `where python` - can never remember which to use)

Comment: the downloadfile is from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.5/python-3.11.5-amd64.exe

@topsail i get a path C:\Users\Cooler Mann\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

However my explorer is crashing/ freezing when right clicking on the .exes

Comment: `python` on Windows where `python` itself hasn't been installed via the Microsoft Store maps to an "App Execution Alias" which triggers the Microsoft Store application to open to the Python page. It's not clear why this doesn't seemingly happen on your system, but the answers on [this cross-site duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor) illustrate how to disable this "feature"

Comment: I have never heard of that. Why would anyone download python from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: I've always considered it a source of weird bugs to use a username with spaces in it. Probably not your problem but you should beware.

Comment: @esqew i edited my text. it shows the window

Comment: @topsail the thing is python worked just fine 10 minutes ago and then it didnt anymore

Comment: after removing the WindowsApp folder and disabling the aliases i get the response from python --version (not installed) however i stiill get py --version. now i need to understand how to "reinstall" python or give visual studio code the command to use py instead of python

Comment: @Guimoute Microsoft actually gives a pretty good rationale for why they did this [on their blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/#installing-python-on-windows) - TL;DR, it boils down to reducing friction, especially for students and others newer to software development, for those whom the relatively vast array of (correct) choices on how to install Python might be confusing or intimidating.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i cant really say how this happened. However what helped:

1 i followed the comment from @esqew and followed this link https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor

2 i uninstalled python completely.

3 i deleted my WindowsApps folder via command shell as admin since my explorer crashed whenever i right clicked the WindowsApps Folder with the following command:
rd /s /q "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"

4 i reinstalled python from the official site and clicked on ADD python.exe to path on the install menu